# Are there major advantages to using DVB-S2 vs CCSDS (or vice-versa)?

Tags: software-defined-radio

In Cubesats, DVB-S2 and CCSDS are both equally present as communications standards.

Are there really any pros and cons, that is - a "best choice for a given application", or are they just standards that have birthed and grown isolated from eachother and have pretty much the same performance and coverage?

Answer (score 3):

DVB-S2 and CCSDS are not two mutually exclusive standards.

DVB-S2 is largely a physical layer standard adopted for RF data transmission from satellites, ratified by the European Telecommunications Standards Institute (ETSI) in 2005.  It was developed with broadcasting in mind, but CCSDS (the Consultative Committee for Space Data Systems) recognized that DVB-S2 physical layer and multi-access protocols could be used as the "front-end" for other data link protocols, eliminating the need to develop something from scratch.

There is a pretty good discussion of CCSDS' thinking here [in this document from 2013](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/131x3b1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're referring to CCSDS DVB-S2, right (looks like so from the title of the linked document)? I was talking about the initial CCSDS standard, does that still apply?

Comment: DVB-S2 is not a CCSDS standard.  It is an ETSI standard.